# Finding the interval of definition for a IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given the differential equation:
$$x^3y''−xy'+y=\frac{1}{x^2}e^{−\frac{1}{x}}, y(1)=y'(1)=\alpha$$
And the general solution of the differential equation to be:
$$y(x)=c_1x+c_2xe^{\frac{−1}{x}}−\frac{e^{\frac{−1}{x}}}{3x^2}−\frac{e^{\frac{−1}{x}}}{x}−2e^{\frac{−1}{x}}.$$
What is the interval of definition for the IVP, where $\alpha$ is some positive real?

Is this the correct approach to find the interval of definition for an IVP?

Changing the differential equation to linear normal form:
$$y''−\frac{1}{x^2}y'+\frac{1}{x^3}y=\frac{1}{x^5}e^{−\frac{1}{x}}$$
Now, looking at the coefficients of the y's and the forcing there are defined everywhere except x = 0. Also, given the initial condition is x = 1 $\implies$ the interval of definition is $(0, \infty)$

Comment: Find values of $x$ for which the equations are invalid. This gives you a first hint of the domain of the system.

Comment: I have updated my post to attempt that approach is this was you were describing?

Comment: Are you sure the equations have no definite value at $x=0$? Look again.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply dividing by 0?

Comment: The equation is irregularly singular at $x=0$, thus it can only be an ODE on a domain that excludes the line $x=0$. This holds without regard to the additional insight that the solutions have a limit for $x\to 0$ at $y(x)\to0$.